# How do I check the % of values in an array that exist in another array in pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a DataFrame in pandas that looks like this:

```
    app_id_x    period  app_id_y
10  [pb6uhl15, xn66n2cr, e68t39yp, s7xun0k1, wab2z...   2015-19 NaN
11  [uscm6kkb, tja4ma8u, qcwhw33w, ux5bbkjz, mmt3s...   2015-20 NaN
12  [txdbauhy, dib24pab, xt69u57g, n9e6a6ol, d9f7m...   2015-21 NaN
13  [21c2b5ca5e7066141b2e2aea35d7253b3b8cce11, oht...   2015-22 [g8m4lecv, uyhsx6lo, u9ue1zzo, kw06m3f5, wvqhq...
14  [64lbiaw3, jum7l6yd, a5d00f6aba8f1505ff22bc1fb...   2015-23 [608a223c57e1174fc64775dd2fd8cda387cc4a47, ze4...
15  [gcg8nc8k, jkrelo7v, g9wqigbc, n806bjdu, piqgv...   2015-24 [kz8udlea, zwqo7j8w, 6d02c9d74b662369dc6c53ccc...
16  [uc311krx, wpd7gm75, am8p0spd, q64dcnlm, idosz...   2015-25 [fgs0qhtf, awkcmpns, e0iraf3a, oht91x5j, mv4uo...
17  [wilhuu0x, b51xiu51, ezt7goqr, qj6w7jh6, pkzkv...   2015-26 [zwqo7j8w, dzdfiof5, phwoy1ea, e7hfx7mu, 40fdd...
18  [xn43bho3, uwtjxy6u, ed65xcuj, ejbgjh61, hbvzt...   2015-27 [ze4rr0vi, kw06m3f5, be532399ca86c053fb0a69d13...
```

What I want to do, is for each `period`, which is a row, check the the % of `app_id_y` values that are also in the list of `app_id_x` values, for that row e.g. if ze4rr0vi  and gm83klja are within `app_id_x` which contains 53 values in that row, then there should be a new column called `adoption_rate` which is:

```
period   adoption_rate
2015-9      0%
2015-22     3.56%
2015-25     4.56%
2015-26     5.10%
2015-35     4.58%
2015-36     1.23%
```

Comment: I think you can use better sample and add desired output of sample. Maybe help - `print pd.DataFrame({'app_id_x': {10: ['pb6uhl15', 'pb6uhl15', 'pb6uhl15'], 11: ['pb6uhl15', 'pb6uhl15', 'e68t39yp', 's7xun0k1'], 12: [ 'pb6uhl15', 's7xun0k1'], 13: [ 's7xun0k1'], 14: ['pb6uhl15', 'pb6uhl15', 'e68t39yp', 's7xun0k1']}, 'app_id_y': {10: ['pb6uhl15'], 11: ['pb6uhl15'], 12: np.nan, 13: ['pb6uhl15', 'xn66n2cr', 'e68t39yp', 's7xun0k1'], 14: ['e68t39yp', 'xn66n2cr']}, 'period': {10: '2015-19', 11: '2015-20', 12: '2015-21', 13: '2015-22', 14: '2015-23'}})` Feel free modify it for better one. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.intersect1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html) to get the common elements between two arrays, which does the bulk of the work that needs to be done.  To get the output, I'm going to write a function to get the overlap percent for a given row, and then use `apply` to add an adoption_rate column.

```
def get_overlap_pcnt(row):
    # Get the overlap between arrays.
    overlap = len(np.intersect1d(row['app_id_x'], row['app_id_y']))

    # Compute the percent common.
    if overlap == 0:
        pcnt = 0
    else:
        pcnt = 100*overlap/len(row['app_id_y'])

    return '{:.2f}%'.format(pcnt)

df['adoption_rate'] = df.apply(get_overlap_pcnt, axis=1)
```

I couldn't quite tell from your question if you wanted `app_id_y` or `app_id_x` to be the denominator, but that's an easy enough change to make.  Below is sample output using some sample data I created.

```
                app_id_x         app_id_y   period adoption_rate
0  [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]              NaN  2015-08         0.00%
1              [b, c, d]     [b, c, d, e]  2015-09        75.00%
2     [a, b, c, x, y, z]        [x, y, z]  2015-10       100.00%
3     [q, w, e, r, t, y]  [a, b, c, d, e]  2015-11        20.00%
4              [x, y, z]        [a, b, x]  2015-12        33.33%
```

Comment: I like this solution. Is there an advantage to using `np.intersect1d` instead of `set`?

Comment: I haven't timed it, but I suspect `np.intersect1d` has better performance for large datasets, as it utilizes numpy's underlying C/C++/Fortran code.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
df[adoption_rate] = [100.*len(set(df.loc[i,app_id_x]) &\ 
                     set(df.loc[i,app_id_y]))/len(set(df.loc[i,app_id_x]))\   
                     if type(df.loc[i,app_id_x])==list and \ 
                     type(df.loc[i,app_id_x])==list \
                     else 0. for i in df.index]
```

Edit: fixed for the case of duplicate values in any of the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

What the other answers are missing is that this is a really unnatural way to store your data. In general, the values in a pandas DataFrame should be scalars.

A better way to represent your data for the purposes of this problem is to reshape them into two dataframes, X and Y. In X, the rows are periods and the columns are the ids (e.g. 'g8m4lecv'). The entries in the X data frame are `1` if the value is in your X column in that period, and similarly for Y.

This makes it much easier to perform the kinds of operations you want to do.

Here goes:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# from the comment by @jezrael . Super useful, thanks
df = pd.DataFrame({'app_id_x': {10: ['pb6uhl15', 'pb6uhl15', 'pb6uhl15'], 11: ['pb6uhl15', 'pb6uhl15', 'e68t39yp', 's7xun0k1'], 12: [ 'pb6uhl15', 's7xun0k1'], 13: [ 's7xun0k1'], 14: ['pb6uhl15', 'pb6uhl15', 'e68t39yp', 's7xun0k1']}, 'app_id_y': {10: ['pb6uhl15'], 11: ['pb6uhl15'], 12: np.nan, 13: ['pb6uhl15', 'xn66n2cr', 'e68t39yp', 's7xun0k1'], 14: ['e68t39yp', 'xn66n2cr']}, 'period': {10: '2015-19', 11: '2015-20', 12: '2015-21', 13: '2015-22', 14: '2015-23'}})


# pulling the data out of the lists in the starting dataframe
new_data = []
for _,row in df.iterrows():
    for col in ['app_id_x','app_id_y']:
        vals = row[col]
        if isinstance(vals,list):
            for v in set(vals):
                new_data.append((row['period'],col[-1],v,1))

new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns = ['period','which_app','val','exists'])

# splitting the data into two frames
def get_one_group(app_id):
    return new_df.groupby('which_app').get_group(app_id).drop('which_app', axis=1)

X = get_one_group('x')
Y = get_one_group('y')


# converting to the desired format
def convert_to_indicator_matrix(df):
    return df.set_index(['period','val']).unstack('val').fillna(0)

X = convert_to_indicator_matrix(X)
Y = convert_to_indicator_matrix(Y)
```

Now, it's super easy to actually solve your problem. I'm not clear on exactly what you need to solve, but suppose you want to know, for each period, `number_ids_in_both` divided by `number_ids_in_Y`.

```
combined = (X * Y).fillna(0)
combined.sum(axis=1) / Y.sum(axis=1)
```